# T-SQL export query results to csv in batches

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL query that returns over 1 million rows. I need to export the returned rows in separate .csv files with about 50000 rows in each.

Is there a way to automate this process?

Comment: will the csv file be opened through excel. Excel 97-2007 only supports 65 536 rows, and Excel 2010 supports 1 048 536 rows.

Comment: Are you using SSRS? It could be setup as a subscription as a .csv to a file server.

Answer (score -2):

I assume you already have a process to export the rows to csv. So all you need to do is add a batch number and then select the batch number in whatever query you are using to get your extract.

To get the batch number use

```
select <your columns>,
row_number() over(order by <maybe created date, PK, etc>) rn/50000 as batchNo
from <your table>
```

Then iterate through the batch numbers.

If your data is likely to change during the process then you could persist it to a temporary or staging table.

Comment: Hey, why the downvote? This is a way to batch up your rows.